# How to clear the content of a file which is locked by a running process?

Tags: shell-script, files, filesystems, io

I am running JMeter on an Ubuntu machine. And running a 12 hour test. 
During this I am observing the log file is increasing to a very big size (around 18 GB).

Is there any way I can use inside a cron job which will clean the content of the file in a regular interval?

I have tried to use `echo -n "" > jmeter-server.log` using `sudo`, but it’s not working as during the test in progress the file is locked by the jmeter-server.sh.

Tried but couldn't find similar post.

Comment: What do you mean by locked? You mean the file is still in use by the process?

Comment: yeah, the file is still being used by the process @EarthMind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo tee thefile </dev/null
```

or:

```
sudo truncate -s 0 thefile
```

Answer (score 1):

Sudo doesn't work as you expect it with forwarding and pipes. If you would sudo your command, it would only sudo the part before **>**. Either do a `sudo bash - c "full command"` or temporarily become root with `sudo -s` and execute your command.

The file being open doesn't block you from editing its contents. It does not remove the file after you delete it though.

Also look into the `copytruncate` option for logrotate

Comment: [This is the 21st century; we shouldn't be recommending `logrotate` any more](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html).  Even JMeter has log4j and its [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) ([also](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-rolling-file-appender/)) now.

Comment: @JdeBP We shouldn't be leaving out a TL;DR in the 21st century either :). After reading the article, I still don't get which practical steps to take to not rely on logrotate.

Comment: Well if "didn't read" includes not even reading the second sentence of that comment, then your idea of "too long" is far too short to be reasonable.

Comment: @JdeBP That post is based on a misconception. "The original way of logging the output of a Unix program was very simple. One just redirects its standard output to a file..." One **does not** "redirect standard output to a file", one [uses a proper logging system](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html) that's [been around since the 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog): "syslog is a standard for message logging. It allows **separation of the software that generates messages, the system that stores them, and the software that reports and analyzes them**."

Comment: (cont) Using redirected `stdout` or `stderr` for logging needlessly ties a long-running process to either a specific file or another process, thereby reducing reliability, availability, and manageability.  It's used by inexperienced developers who don't know better, and it's also a characteristic of low-quality/low-cost software that doesn't have strict availability and/or maintainability requirements.